# HTML code into README.md on Github

Tags: github, markdown

I tried to put some HTML snippets into my README.md on Github but the HTML codes are parsed.

How do I do it?

```
<h2>Example of code</h2>

<pre>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block two first">
            <h2>Your title</h2>
            <div class="wrap">
                //Your content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Try putting your HTML snippet inside an ```` ```HTML ```` block like this:

````
```html
<h2>Example of code</h2>

<pre>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="block two first">
            <h2>Your title</h2>
            <div class="wrap">
            //Your content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</pre>
```
````

Comment: @tonymx227 It's a feature of the redcarpet library which GitHub uses for Markdown rendering: https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet. See the "fenced code blocks" option.

Comment: @IvanZuzak Thank you - it works for me. It seems you have to make sure you put your HTML is in the second line as you have shown in your example.

Comment: awesome! This worked for the markdown plugin in JetBrains IDEs

Comment: you can use this ```   ```  to pass any code